# How to create an immutable lazy property?

Tags: swift

I have 2 classes. `Child` class needs a reference to `Parent` in its initializer.

```
class Child {
     init(parent: Parent)
}

class Parent {
   init()
   public lazy var child: Child = Child(parent: self)
}
```

Since I can't use `self` in the init() of Parent to construct its `child` property. I create a `lazy var` for the `child` property, like this:

```
public lazy var child: Child = Child(parent: self)
```

But I need to make it to `var` in order to mark it lazy. Is there a way to make the `child` immutable and able to construct it once when the `child` property is called?

Comment: The approach Is not good anyway because it causes a retain cycle if both properties are strong. Declare the `child` property in `Parent` as `weak var child : Child!` and assign the value in the initializer of `Child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, that's not possible. As per Swift documentation:

> Constant properties must always have a value before initialization
> completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.

Link: [Swift lazy documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#:%7E:text=A%20lazy%20stored%20property%20is,first%20time%20it%20is%20used.&text=Constant%20properties%20must%20always%20have,cannot%20be%20declared%20as%20lazy.)

You can declare `child` as `private(set)` so it can only be changed from inside your class.